# Google Cloud platform. npm install - (bash) npm command not found. How to repair Google cloud shell

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, google-app-engine, developer-console

I created new project in https://console.developers.google.com .
Cloned one project from git, then issued command:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

and

```
gcloud init
```

after doing this I'm no longer able to call

```
npm install
```

command, because cloud shell throws error

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

how can I revert (repair) Cloud shell to its primary state.

I even can't make Node.js example projects...

---

also

```
 node -v
```

returns

```
 bash: node: command not found
```

Comment: edit your post to include output from `echo PATH="$PATH"`. You probably just need to reset  your PATH to include dirs for node and npm. Good luck.

Comment: Hold on, is this on Cloud Shell? Cloud Shell already has gcloud installed, you shouldn't have to install it!

Comment: @shellter it output:
PATH=/home/benas/ls/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

I fixed "npm: command not found" by reinstalling Node.js:

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

then

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

it's hard to read this way, so I will post it as an answer

Comment: by the way, thank you for helping me.

@Sandeep Dinesh yes I should't had to install  gcloud one more time... :)

Comment: You're welcome. That's why we're here at S.O. BUT I think @SandeepDinesh is onto something about gcloud. I would run another test, and eliminate you call to `gcloud init`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled node.

At first I removed this dir:

```
 rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then used these commands, since VM OS is Linux:

```
 curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

finally:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

instructions are taken from

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

---

now `echo PATH="$PATH"` outputs:

```
 PATH=/home/benas/ls/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

---

after all I decided to delete my google account and start everything from scratch, that is I created new account which had poperly working developer console.